# useCallback doesn't call setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I face an issue when using useCallback hook of react. When I use normal arrow functions, It calls the setSlimSideBar(!slimSideBar) but useCallback doesn't call or not setting value as expected.

```
const [slimSideBar, setSlimSideBar] = useState(true)
```

This set state as Expected.

```
const toggle = () => {
    console.log(slimSideBar)
    console.log(!slimSideBar)

    setSlimSideBar(!slimSideBar)
}
```

The below function doesn't set the state as I expected.

```
 const toggle = React.useCallback(() => {
        console.log(slimSideBar)
        console.log(!slimSideBar)

        setSlimSideBar(!slimSideBar)
    },[setSlimSideBar])
```

Any Ideas why useCallback doesn't call setSlimBar function?

Answer (score 2):

What `useCallback` does is, it will return the new function passed into it *if* any of the items in its dependency array have changed (are `===`, essentially) since last render. State setters are stable references; your `setSlimSideBar` will refer to exactly the same function over the whole life of the component. As a result:

```
const toggle = React.useCallback(() => {
    // ...
},[setSlimSideBar])
```

Because the only item in the dependency array never changes, the function returned by `useCallback` never changes.

Add `slimSideBar` to the dependency array so that when it changes, the returned function changes as well.

```
const toggle = React.useCallback(() => {
    // ...
},[slimSideBar, setSlimSideBar]);
```

Or use the callback form of the state setter, so you don't have to rely on the outer state variable being up-to-date.

```
const toggle = React.useCallback(() => {
    setSlimSideBar(slimSideBar => !slimSideBar);
},[setSlimSideBar]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. I've just tested. Your suggestion works perfectly. Many thanks